# Reduce Array of Array of Objects Using Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ramda.js

I have an array of array of objects. I want to reduce that to an array of object and adding one more property to each object.
The sample input is:

```
const data = [
    [
        {name:"a", val:5},
        {name:"b", val:10},
        {name:"c", val:20},
        {name:"d", val:50},
        {name:"e", val:100}
    ],
    [
        {name:"a", val:0},
        {name:"b", val:20},
        {name:"c", val:30},
        {name:"d", val:40},
        {name:"e", val:10}
    ],
    [
        {name:"a", val:60},
        {name:"b", val:50},
        {name:"c", val:40},
        {name:"d", val:70},
        {name:"e", val:30}
    ]
];
```

And the Output should be:

```
[{name: 'a', val: 65, rank: 'si'},
 {name: 'b', val: 80, rank: 'dp'},
 {name: 'c', val: 90, rank: 'en'}
 {name: 'd', val: 160, rank: 'fr'}]
```

`Rank` is static text means for `a`, it will always be `"si"`
How can I achieve this using **ramda**?

Comment: Are we to guess as to how the `rank` is generated? Grouping and summing is covered by a few different questions: [using ramda group by property and sum results on specified property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45739479/215552), [Grouping and summing in Ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27214451/215552), [How to group by a key and sum other keys with Ramda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60423794/215552)

Comment: that is static text.

Comment: I am assuming the a, b, c, d in the resulting array are the sum of all as, bs, cs, ds in the original array but since your `b` total is incorrect and should be 80 instead of 90 if you follows that pattern, I have to ask are those actually sums or is there some other algorithm?

Comment: @codemonkey yes, I have corrected that :) That is actually sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert flatten all sub arrays to a single array, group by the `name`, and then map the groups, and reduce each group to a single object using R.mergeWithKey to add the `val` property. Convert back to an array using R.values, and map to add the static ranks property by `name`.

Note that you must create a Map or a dictionary object to take the rank by `name` from.

```js
const { mergeWithKey, pipe, flatten, groupBy, prop, map, reduce, values } = R

const ranks = new Map([['a', 'si'], ['b', 'dp'], ['c', 'en'], ['d', 'fr']])

// merge deep and combine val property values
const combine = mergeWithKey((k, l, r) => k == 'val' ? l + r : r)

const mergeData = pipe(
  flatten, // flatten to a single array
  groupBy(prop('name')), // group by the name
  map(reduce(combine, {})), // combine each group to a single object
  values, // convert back to array
  map(o => ({ ...o, rank: ranks.get(o.name) })), // add the static rank property
)

const data = [[{"name":"a","val":5},{"name":"b","val":10},{"name":"c","val":20},{"name":"d","val":50},{"name":"e","val":100}],[{"name":"a","val":0},{"name":"b","val":20},{"name":"c","val":30},{"name":"d","val":40},{"name":"e","val":10}],[{"name":"a","val":60},{"name":"b","val":50},{"name":"c","val":40},{"name":"d","val":70},{"name":"e","val":30}]]

const results = mergeData(data)

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Just one thing, in your solution, you are also returning `name: "e"` object as well. That is not required

Comment: You can always add a filter after flattening to remove unwanted objects.

Comment: One thing more, you have used `map` whereas we can use `object` there. Is there a specific reason you used `map`?

Comment: Maps are more idiomatic, and the key can be any type of value, but in this case is mostly a personal preference.