# Reduce multiple properties in array of array of objects and omit other properties using Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have this array of arrays with objects:

```
const data = [
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 2,
      value: '31011784785',
      participants: 1222,
      cost: '1286828506'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '111306385',
      participants: 18,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '14550473',
      participants: 10,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 1,
      value: '7089001673',
      participants: 492,
      cost: '648196615'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '13551137',
      participants: 8,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '11499815',
      participants: 5,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 1,
      value: '408900161',
      participants: 200,
      cost: '648196615'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '23551231',
      participants: 10,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '104324219',
      participants: 5,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to make a single array with objects that will have just the properties index, value, and participants where value and participants will be the sum of the 3 arrays. Eg:

```
[
  {
      index: 320,
      value: 38509686619,
      participants: 1914,
  },
  {
      index: 319,
      value: 148408753,
      participants: 36,
  },
  {
     ...
  }
]
```

I would also like the value field to be a BigInt.

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602761/10527970) I made something that works but it's way too long and cumbersome.

This question is different from [Reduce Array of Array of Objects Using Ramda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602396/reduce-array-of-array-of-objects-using-ramda/) because I need two object property values and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce Array of Array of Objects Using Ramda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602396/reduce-array-of-array-of-objects-using-ramda)

Comment: It was a good starting point but I don't know how to add 2 properties in that combine under ```map(reduce(combine, {})) ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Ramda approach:

```js
const convert = pipe (
  transpose,
  map (xs => ({
    index: xs [0] .index,
    value: xs .reduce ((a, {value}) => a + Number (value), 0),
    participants: sum (pluck ('participants') (xs))
  }))
) 

const data = [[{index: 320, blocks: 2, value: "31011784785", participants: 1222, cost: "1286828506"}, {index: 319, blocks: 0, value: "111306385", participants: 18, cost: "0"}, {index: 318, blocks: 0, value: "14550473", participants: 10, cost: "0"}], [{index: 320, blocks: 1, value: "7089001673", participants: 492, cost: "648196615"}, {index: 319, blocks: 0, value: "13551137", participants: 8, cost: "0"}, {index: 318, blocks: 0, value: "11499815", participants: 5, cost: "0"}], [{index: 320, blocks: 1, value: "408900161", participants: 200, cost: "648196615"}, {index: 319, blocks: 0, value: "23551231", participants: 10, cost: "0"}, {index: 318, blocks: 0, value: "104324219", participants: 5, cost: "0"}]]

console .log (convert (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, transpose, map, sum, pluck, reduce, applySpec} = R </script>
```

We start with `transpose`, which turns this into a much easier to work with format.  Then for each new row, we grab the index from the first record, and sum up both the participants and the values.

Because BigInt's don't show well in the SO console, I skipped them, but the change is trivial:

```
-    value: xs .reduce ((a, {value}) => a + Number (value), 0),
+    value: xs .reduce ((a, {value}) => a + BigInt(value), BigInt(0)),
```

A point-free version, if you have that fetish, is not much harder:

```js
const convert = pipe (
  transpose,
  map (applySpec ({
    index: pipe (head, prop ('index')),
    value: reduce ((a, {value}) => a + Number (value), 0),
    // value: reduce ((a, {value}) => a + BigInt (value), BigInt (0)),
    participants: pipe (pluck ('participants'), sum)
  }))
)
```

Comment: Great solution as always, thank you, Scott!

Answer (score 3):

Vanila JS solution:

```js
const data = [[{"index":320,"blocks":2,"value":"31011784785","participants":1222,"cost":"1286828506"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"111306385","participants":18,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"14550473","participants":10,"cost":"0"}],[{"index":320,"blocks":1,"value":"7089001673","participants":492,"cost":"648196615"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"13551137","participants":8,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"11499815","participants":5,"cost":"0"}],[{"index":320,"blocks":1,"value":"408900161","participants":200,"cost":"648196615"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"23551231","participants":10,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"104324219","participants":5,"cost":"0"}]];


const result = Object.values(data.flat()
  .reduce((acc, { index, value, participants }) => {
    acc[index] ??= { index, value: 0, participants: 0 };
    acc[index].value += Number(value);
    acc[index].participants += Number(participants);
  
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! Great input!

Answer (score 1):

After flattening, the array of arrays, you should map and pick the wanted properties and convert `values` to a number, and then group by, and combine each group to a single object.

```js
const { mergeWithKey, pipe, flatten, map, pick, evolve, groupBy, prop, reduce, values } = R

// merge deep and combine properties value
const combine = mergeWithKey((k, l, r) => k === 'value' || k === 'participants' ? l + r : r)

const mergeData = pipe(
  flatten, // flatten to a single array
  map(pipe(
    pick(['index', 'value', 'participants']), // pick wanted properties
    evolve({ value: Number }) // convert values to a number
  )),
  groupBy(prop('index')), // group by the name
  map(reduce(combine, {})), // combine each group to a single object
  values, // convert back to array
)

const data = [[{"index":320,"blocks":2,"value":"31011784785","participants":1222,"cost":"1286828506"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"111306385","participants":18,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"14550473","participants":10,"cost":"0"}],[{"index":320,"blocks":1,"value":"7089001673","participants":492,"cost":"648196615"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"13551137","participants":8,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"11499815","participants":5,"cost":"0"}],[{"index":320,"blocks":1,"value":"408900161","participants":200,"cost":"648196615"},{"index":319,"blocks":0,"value":"23551231","participants":10,"cost":"0"},{"index":318,"blocks":0,"value":"104324219","participants":5,"cost":"0"}]]

const results = mergeData(data)

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. At the evolve I replaced Number with BigInt.

Answer (score 1):

This solution (using JS and not rambda) attempts to use BigInt and provides the value into a prop named `valueB`.

```js
const groupAndSum = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.flat().reduce(
      (acc, {index, value, participants}) => ({
        ...acc,
        [index]: {
          index,
          valueB: BigInt((acc[index]?.valueB ?? 0)) + BigInt(value), // valueB as big-int
          value: (acc[index]?.value || 0) + +value, // value as a "Number"
          participants: (acc[index]?.participants ?? 0) + +participants
        }
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).map( // to display big-int in the console within stack-snippets
    ({valueB, ...rest}) => ({valueB: valueB.toString(), ...rest})
  )
);

const data = [
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 2,
      value: '31011784785',
      participants: 1222,
      cost: '1286828506'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '111306385',
      participants: 18,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '14550473',
      participants: 10,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 1,
      value: '7089001673',
      participants: 492,
      cost: '648196615'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '13551137',
      participants: 8,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '11499815',
      participants: 5,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      index: 320,
      blocks: 1,
      value: '408900161',
      participants: 200,
      cost: '648196615'
    },
    {
      index: 319,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '23551231',
      participants: 10,
      cost: '0'
    },
    {
      index: 318,
      blocks: 0,
      value: '104324219',
      participants: 5,
      cost: '0'
    }
  ]
];

console.log(groupAndSum(data));
```

**Explanation**

- `Object.values()` is used to extract the values of the resulting-object from below operations
- First, the input array is `flat`tened to remove the nesting
- Next, `.reduce` is used to iterate through the array and generate a result-object
- `acc` is the accumulator/aggregator object
- Each `index` is either added into `acc` as a new key with the value being the actual object
- If the `index` was already present in `acc`, then the `value` and `participants` props are summed-up.
- `valueB` is a new prop to store the `BigInt` format of `value`

An additional `.map()` is used to make `valueB` displayable within the `console.log` on stack-snippets. This may not be required in the original code - so, please ignore.